# Tире или дефис в "сервис - конкурент"?

Tags: пунктуация, орфография

В фразе "Cмогли бы создать сервис-конкурент?", где `сервис-конкурент` означает "сервис, который является (являлся бы) конкурентом - нужно ли тут писать тире или дефис?

Comment: дефис и только дефис

Answer (score 4):

Дефис. `сервис-конкурент`.

Тире - это знак синтаксиса, который участвует в формировании предложения, заменяя пропущеный или подразумеваемый член, а здесь просто слово, состоящее из двух частей.

> Дефис в русской письменности
>
> Правила, регламентирующие раздельное — дефисное — слитное написание,
>   содержат множество исключений, которые указаны в словарях. Вот
>   некоторые случаи дефисного написания:
>
> составные слова (горе-охотник, луна-парк, Ага-хан, генерал-майор,
>   жар-птица, пиар-акция, киловатт-час, Санкт-Петербург, интернет-сайт,
>   онлайн-голосование);

<sup>[Источник](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81#%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81_%D0%B2_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)</sup>

Comment: во всех этих примерах первое слово определяет второе слово. в моем случае это как бы подлежащее и сказуемое

Comment: qdinar, если это не единое понятие "сервисконкурент",  (из вашего вопроса это, кстати, не ясно), то дефиса там быть не может.

Comment: возможно определение второго слова первым - это правило, ([или кажущееся правило, потому что оно, вероятно, ещё не сформулировано](http://zovu.ru/index.php?dn=news&to=art&id=1621)), особенно в терминах иностранного происхождения, где дефис соединяет слова английской сопряжённой конструкции, но не железное: **изба-читальня, мать-героиня, страсти-мордасти, путь-дорога, жёлто-зелёный, ванька-встанька, акробат-жонглёр, массовик-затейник** - здесь обе части можно сказать равноправны

Comment: по описанию в вопросе можно понять, что то, о чём идёт речь является одновременно и сервисом, и конкурентом, но если это сервис, единственная или главная задача которого составлять конкуренцию, а уверенности по поводу дефиса нет, то можно сказать и "конкурирующий сервис"